# GnuPG: Show full fingerprint of certificate signatures

Tags: signature, gnupg, pgp

I am looking for an offline way to view the full fingerprint of the people who signed a public-key.

```
me@my-PC:~$ gpg --list-sig bilbo@shire.org
pub   4096R/19ED3242 2015-08-06 [expires: 2016-08-05]
uid                  Bilbo Baggins <bilbo@shire.org>
sig 3        19ED3242 2015-08-06  Bilbo Baggins <bilbo@shire.org>
sig   L      97F6C54A 2015-08-07  Frodo Baggins <frodo@shire.org>
uid                  [jpeg image of size 13199]
sig 3        19ED3242 2015-08-06  Bilbo Baggins <bilbo@shire.org>
sub   4096R/A182F292 2015-08-06 [expires: 2016-08-05]
sig          19ED3242 2015-08-06  Bilbo Baggins <bilbo@shire.org>
```

I only see the 8-byte fingerprint of Frodo "97F6C54A" but how do I view the full fingerprint?

Comment: With a recent gpg you get at least the 16-character ID.

Answer (score 1):

Run `gpg --fingerprint [key-id]` to resolve a key ID (or also user ID) to a key from your local keyring.